# How to make large graph by using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a file "Account.csv" with bank accounts and a file "Trade_History.csv" with transaction history between accounts. Account.csv has only "id" column and Trade_History.csv has two columns "from" and "to". Now I would like to graph the accounts and transactions using Neo4j, a graph database. I am new to Neo4j so I would appreciate it if you could tell me the way to do this.

I coded as follows;
First, I imported the two files. Here I use apoc.import.csv instead of LOAD_CSV because the two files are very large.

```
CALL apoc.import.csv(
            [{fileName: "file:///Account.csv", labels: ["Account"]}],
            [],
            {}
        )

CALL apoc.import.csv(
            [{fileName: "file:///Trade_History.csv", labels: ["Trade_History"]}],
            [],
            {}
        )
```

Next, the two nodes were matched to each other as follows.

```
MATCH (c:Trade_History)
MATCH (b:Account) where b.id = c.to with b, c
MATCH (a:Account) WHERE a.id = c.from with a, c
CREATE (a)-[r:TRANSACTION]->(c)
```

However, I got the following error;

> MemoryPoolOutOfMemoryError.
> The allocation of an extra 2.0 MiB would use more than the limit 5.6 GiB. Currently using 5.6 GiB. dbms.memory.transaction.total.max threshold reached

It seems to be an error of not enough memory, how should I solve it? Or is there some problem with the query itself? In the first place, my approach to the problem may not be the best, so I would very much appreciate your suggestions for improvement.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not fully using [apoc.import.csv](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/import/import-csv/), which is capable of loading the nodes and relationships for you in one call (but only for "small- to medium-sized data sets"). For large amounts of data, you should use [neo4j-admin database import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/neo4j-admin-import/) instead.

To use `apoc.import.csv` correctly, try this:

- Use this header row in `Account.csv`:

  ```
  :ID
  ```
- Use this header row in `Trade_History.csv` (assuming that your "from" id comes before the "to" id):

  ```
  :START_ID,:END_ID
  ```
- Execute this Cypher statement:

  ```
  CALL apoc.import.csv(
    [{fileName: "file:///Account.csv", labels: ["Account"]}],
    [{fileName: 'file:///Trade_History.csv', type: 'TRANSACTION'}],
    {}
  )
  ```

Comment: Dear cybersam

Thank you for your quick reply. 
Thank you very much for the detailed information about loading queries. Neo4j allows me to create relationships while loading nodes, it is very informative! Also, thank you for the information about the best query depending on the volume of data to be loaded. I would like to study it more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to batch your transactions when dealing with large graphs. You could use batching subqueries

```
MATCH (c:Trade_History)
CALL {
  WITH c
  MATCH (b:Account) WHERE b.id = c.to with b, c
  MATCH (a:Account) WHERE a.id = c.from with a, c
  CREATE (a)-[r:TRANSACTION]->(c)
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 1000 ROWS
```

Probably you also want to create a transaction between a and b ->

```
CREATE (a)-[r:TRANSACTION]->(b)
```

Comment: Dear Tomaž Bratanič

Thank you for your quick reply.
I did not know about the batch batching subqueries. I understood that processing is done gradually, not all at once, to reduce memory usage.Thank you very much for your instruction! I would like to study it more.
I tried it and got the message,"Variable `c` not defined". So I put the first line in the CALL statement and it worked successfully. I wonder if this is correct... I would appreciate it if you could let me know when you are free.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of correcting the query by adding `WITH c` to the top of the subquery. Also note that you will probably want to delete all your `Trade_History` nodes after the relationships are created. This creation and deletion of temporary nodes is one reason why this overall approach is not really recommended.